# Composability: Iterator vs Lambda

Tags: python, design-patterns, functional-programming, composable

I am having trouble understanding the concept of 'good' functional composability.  Assume the following approaches for deleting files with a specific extension:

Using Lambda functions:

```
def traverse_tree(
        temp_storage: Local, extensions: List[str], is_raw: bool, operation: Callable
):
    for folder_path, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(temp_storage.root_path(is_raw)):
        for filename in filenames:
            base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
            if ext in extensions:
                file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
                operation(file_path)

def clear_temp(
        temp_storage, extensions: List[str], is_raw
):
    traverse_tree(temp_storage=temp_storage, extensions=extensions, is_raw=True, operation=lambda x: os.remove(x))
```

Using an iterator:

```
def traverse_tree(
        temp_storage, extensions: List[str], is_raw
):
    for folder_path, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(temp_storage.root_path(is_raw)):
        for filename in filenames:
            base, ext = os.path.split(filename)
            if ext in extensions:
                file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
                yield file_path


def clear_temp(
        temp_storage: Local, extensions: List[str], is_raw: bool
):
    for path in traverse_tree(temp_storage, extensions, is_raw):
        os.remove(path)
```

Is one approach favored over the other in terms of modularity and ease of debugging? If so, can you give an example where one approach objectively results in less flexibility?

Thanks,

Comment: The second example is more flexible, because the function just yields the items to the caller, which can do anything it wants with them.  The first example imposes an unnecessary limitation, which is that the caller MUST be able to express its desired usage as a function of one argument.  The simpler (iterator) approach hews better to the single responsibility principle.

Comment: Did you mean to say the iterator (2nd version) is more flexible ?
edit: Thanks!

Comment: Iterators are more flexible than these kind of visitors/lambdas.  For example, client code can have multiple iterators and decide when to step each one further through the result set, doing other work or checks, whereas the visitor/lambda version wants to do an operation to every member before the caller gets to do anything else.  Of course you can shoe-horn extra work unrelated to the currently visited element into the functor/lambda, but that would be spectacularly clumsy and counter-intuitive.  You can also use itertools  and similar to compose functionality around iteration(s).

Comment: As a functional programming enthusiast and someone who favour simple things, I'd prefer the approach that's returning an iterator over the one that takes a function and then executes it as a side-effect. But I wouldn't call one approach more functional or composable than the other. See my blog post on [Composable Abstractions in Practice](https://mb21.github.io/blog/2021/09/11/composable-abstractions.html) for some examples...

Answer (score 0):

Your question has nothing to do with functional composability - you aren't composing functions.

It seems to be that you are having a hard time justifying whether `operation: Callable` is even needed and what good use it has (if any at all). The problem with your example is that it is oversimplified. How would you add renaming of (some) files matching the arbitrary complex pattern? Would you copy/paste another version of literally the same code **with the only difference in the body of the `for` loop** that materializes the `iterator`?

One (pretty common and justified by practice) way of achieving it is **extracting a higher-order function** out of it and taking it as an argument. Such a trick does not work well in languages like good old C where you can't have a well-typed (if only C had some well-typed-ness...) function as a first-class object and have no anonymous functions (also known as "lambdas" - a term that came from the [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus)). But Python does have it - as well as many other modern languages do!

With that bit, you can **reuse** the same piece of code and make it kinda polymorphic up to the implementation of all the (function) arguments it takes. More to say, this is exactly how widely recognized "purely functional" programming languages like Haskell structure the codebase, in particular - their standard libraries. Another good example of this approach is Python's `filter` and `map` - both expect you to provide a function that does the filtering/mapping such that **a single implementation** could have taken a good care over iteration itself.